# Typescript Promise chaining - changing the returned type

Tags: typescript, promise, typescript-generics

I have two async gets I'd like to call, the second which uses the output of the first one, and their returned types (within the Promise) are different.

These are from the `AsyncStorage` library in React.

My code is:

```
    function fetchAllSecretsRaw(): Promise<[string, string | null][]> {
        return AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then((allKeys) => {
            return AsyncStorage.multiGet(allKeys.filter(isSecretKey));
        });
    }
```

I am surprised that this typechecks when looking at the Promise declaration. How does this work? How can `Promise<[string, string | null][]>` satisfy `Promise<string[]>` (which comes from `TResult1 = T`?

The async functions signatures are:

```
getAllKeys(callback?: (error?: Error, keys?: string[]) => void): Promise<string[]>;

  multiGet(
    keys: string[],
    callback?: (errors?: Error[], result?: [string, string | null][]) => void
  ): Promise<[string, string | null][]>;
```

while .then on a `Promise<T>` is:

```
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null,
        onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;
```

The first `getAllKeys()` gives me a `Promise<string[]>`, which according to the Promise declaration means that `T=string[]`

Since `TResult1 = T` (from then's declaration `then<TResult1 = T,`) does that mean `TResult1 = string[]`?

But the `onfulfilled` function I pass actually returns a `Promise<[string, string | null][]>`, i.e. a tuple array instead of a string array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the `.then` declaration also constrains that `TResult1 = T`

No, it doesn't constrain it (like an `extends` clause would) - that's only a default value for when no `onfulfilled` callback is provided.

But you did provide one, and its type is `(value: string[]) => Promise<[string, string | null][]>`, so `TResult1` is properly inferred to `[string, string | null][]`.

Comment: Thanks! I never considered that the `=` was actually a default value on the type parameter.  I couldn't find an explanation of `=` in the docs

Comment: @achow Oh wow this is woefully missing in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html :-( I found some documentation [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/generic-parameter-defaults-in-typescript). It appears that quite many TypeScript language features are not documented but only announced in the TypeScript blog, in this case https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-3/#default-type-arguments

Answer (score 2):

`TResult1` is the type of the return value of the `onfulfilled` function (in your case `[string, string | null][]`) OR if `onfulfilled` is absent the type of `T` (in your case `string[]`).

Since your `onfulfilled` function is:

```
(allKeys) => {
  return AsyncStorage.multiGet(allKeys.filter(isSecretKey));
}
```

which returns a `Promise<[string, string | null][]>`. This therefore type checks fine. It is not a mistake.

Comment: But the `.then` declaration also constrains that `TResult1 = T`. So we have two conflicting TResult1, `Promise<[string, string | null][]>` and `Promise<T>`, where T is `string[]`

Comment: Ah, I see where the confusion is coming from! I should've read a bit better, but answered in a bit of a hurry. `TResult1` is not constrained to `T`. Its default value is set to `T`. This means that when `onfulfilled` is absent and therefore `TResult1` is unknown, the type value for `TResult1` will be `T` and thus the return value for `then` will be `Promise<T>`.